# How is Magento using the module_name tag elements in the module config file

Tags: magento, config

I found [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/module_config.xml) that Magento is using these tags as custom config variables, but I still cannot understand where are they used and how.
For example the Wishlist module has **wishlist** (same name as the module) xml tag in the config.xml file in which it defines:

```
<item>
    <product_attributes>
        <visibility/>
        <url_path/>
        <url_key/>
    </product_attributes>
</item>
```

Where is this module using these configurations?
Also if I was to build payment method, I have to add in my custom module config.xml a tag for **sales** and then for **quote** and so on...
I also found other related questions, but most of the answers were that these tags can be anything, but I need to know how they are used by the system.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the file directly responsible is `app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Config.php` where consists entirely of this:

```
class Mage_Wishlist_Model_Config
{
    const XML_PATH_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES = 'global/wishlist/item/product_attributes';

    /**
     * Get product attributes that need in wishlist
     *
     */
    public function getProductAttributes()
    {
        $attrsForCatalog  = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();
        $attrsForWishlist = Mage::getConfig()->getNode(self::XML_PATH_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES)->asArray();

        return array_merge($attrsForCatalog, array_keys($attrsForWishlist));
    }
}
```

So whenever you need to read the config specifically just use **`Mage::getConfig()->getNode()`** and pass the path of the node that interests you. In this example the path is `global/wishlist/item/product_attributes`, which you already know.

Each module will read it's configuration as it needs and there is no formal definition. This flexibility allows any module to contribute to any other module's settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me look around the classes and found out that these attributes are used in the Wishlist Item collection model as product attributes to be selected in _afterLoad method, so logical conclusion would be that these custom configuration values are used ONLY internally by the specific Module classes and I can add my own as well. Am i right about this?

Comment: Yes. You can define any content you wish in an extensible way.